# SailsJS get own socket ID on client

Tags: websocket, socket.io, sails.js, sails.io.js

How can I get the socket ID on the client side in a clean way? I already use `io.socket._raw.id` to access the socket ID, but this is more a hack I think. I can't find a function like io.socket.getId() or something similar to get the socket ID.